# .hasClass() seem to always return true when used inside a .click() function, why?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

$('#list li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).hasClass('active')); // supposed to be an if
    $(this).parent('ul').children('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Why does "$(this).hasClass('active')" always return true?

Comment: it doesn't always return true. http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/

Comment: I did exactly the same as you - never seen jsfiddle before - looks like a less fussy version of jsbin (one screen only). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong with your code? For the first time it will false as per given HTML. But next time if you're clicking on same item then only it return true else it returns false only.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qSmTQ/1/)

Comment: Oh, rookie mistake, on a second review of my perhaps a bit confusing code I spot another click function that sets that class. Thank you anyways, nice to see that you get a quick response on here!

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't

http://jsbin.com/ubocu3/2

it returns false (the first time)

Comment: your code returns true when you click second time , thats the desired behavior

Comment: I know - I should have been more specific I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#list li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).hasClass('active')); // supposed to be an if
    $(this).parent('ul').children('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

$(this).hasClass('active') is used to fetch element with that class name.

if u want to check availability of class use this code

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

$('#list li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).isClass('active')); // alert returns true if element has that class
if($(this).is('.active'))
{    
    $(this).parent('ul').children('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
});
```